# Accessing the connection string in Entity Framework Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I'm doing my first app in .NET 6 and using Entity Framework Core 6, using database first and the `Scaffold-DbContext` command to create the `DbContext`.

The only issue I have is trying to use the `Name={connection string name}` parameter rather than embedding the connection string. The app is a simple Console app (not an ASP.NET app) with an `app.config` file (can't use a JSON config file for other reasons). I added the connection to the config file like:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabase" 
         connectionString="Server=xxxxxxx;Database=xxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I get this error:

> A named connection string was used, but the name 'ClientServices' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information.

What do I need to do so that the `Scaffold-DbContext` `Name` parameter can find my connection string? Looked at the link in the error, but it didn't help - was for ASP.NET apps.

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid ASP.Net kind of Startup class with ConfigureService method? Are you ok to have the ASP.Net like service configuration class?

Comment: Console apps can use the same generic host / DI / appsettings.json pattern. With either a top level builder, or a `CreateHostBuilder` method, so the command line tools can discover your config & types.

Comment: Thanks much! I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is struggeling with this, here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) that should help you out.

For a WPF app, you should at least ad this code for the scaffold command to work:

```
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
  using System.Windows;


  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    public App()
    {
      using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().Build();

      var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

      host.Run();
    }
  }
```

Put the code in Program.cs/Main in case this matches your project's template.